# What are all the default maven packing types?

Tags: packaging, maven-3

I couldn't seem to find this online or in the Maven documentation; I was wondering what packaging types are supported out of the box with Maven 3. Is there a test package?

Please and thank you.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

> The current core packaging values are: **pom**, **jar**, **maven-plugin**, **ejb**, **war**, **ear**, **rar**, **par**.

https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#packaging

Comment: ejb3 is also now a distinct mapping, and the are several recognised additional types that can used for dependencies but not packaging (ejb-client, test-jar, javadoc, java-source)

Comment: appears you can also pass whatever you want for packaging, like "tar.gz"?

Comment: You'll find a better documented list in the maven book: http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/lifecycle-sect-package-specific.html