# What are the utilities of packaging in pom file ? What are values that can take packaging and what is their meaning?

Tags: maven

There is the pom file, it contains a packaging field

```
<!-- The Basics -->
      <groupId>...</groupId>
      <artifactId>...</artifactId>
      <version>...</version>
      <packaging>...</packaging>
      <dependencies>...</dependencies>
      <parent>...</parent>
      <dependencyManagement>...</dependencyManagement>
      <modules>...</modules>
      <properties>...</properties>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packaging defines which type of artifact you are building, e.g. jar or war (full list of core packaging : [What are all the default maven packing types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544019/what-are-all-the-default-maven-packing-types/5544301)).

It has influence on the Maven lifecycle that is running, especially how the code is compiled and packaged.